# Powerhsell script to use returned value

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell function that runs every 10s to check a port is open:

```
$output_file = 'C:\networktest-out.txt';
$port = '9392';
$cloud_gate_name = '192.168.100.8';
while ($true) {Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $cloud_gate_name -port $port >> $output_file; 
start-sleep -s 10; Add-Content $output_file -Value $(Get-Date -Format G)}
```

The result of this function is :

```
ComputerName     : 192.168.100.8
RemoteAddress    : 192.168.100.8
RemotePort       : 9392
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 192.168.100.8
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

How would I test the TcpTestSucceeded=True everytime it runs, and if the result is False run seperate code like below

```
if ($TcpTestSucceeded eq False) 
{ someother command }
```

PS: Will also need to modify first command to send to std out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $output_file = 'C:\networktest-out.txt'
    $port = '9392'
    $cloud_gate_name = '192.168.100.8'
    $check = $false
    
do {

    $test = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $cloud_gate_name -port $port
    $check = $test.TcpTestSucceeded
    $(Get-Date -Format G) |Out-File -FilePath $output_file -Append -Encoding utf8
    $test |Out-File -FilePath $output_file -Append -Encoding utf8

    if (!($check) ){Wait-Event -Timeout 10}

} until ($check)
```