# PowerShell try / catch not capturing exception for System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

Tags: powershell

Take the PowerShell function (below) which uses System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping to send a ping request with a timeout in PowerShell 5.1.

This works perfectly most of the time, but every so often $Ping.Send fails on line 9 with the following exception:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a Ping request."
At <script path, redacted>
+             $PingReply = $Ping.Send($ComputerName, $Timeout * 1000)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PingException
```

It appears to be related to random networking issues, so I want to just ignore this and treat it as a 'failed' Ping. But the try / catch loop doesn't work.

I have tried *catch*ing 'System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException' and 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException'.

What is wrong with this script to mean the exception is still thrown?

```
Function Test-Ping { # Use this instead of Test-Connection to allow increasing timeout
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$ComputerName,
        [Parameter()][Int32]$Timeout = 15,
        [Parameter()][Int32]$Retries = 5
    )
    $Ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    while ($Retries -ne 0) {
        try {
            $PingReply = $Ping.Send($ComputerName, $Timeout * 1000)
            if ($PingReply.Status -eq 'Success') {
                return $true
            }
        }
        catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] { # Sometimes get error 'Exception calling "Send" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a Ping request."' - treat this as a failure
            return $false
        }
        $Retries--
    }
    $Ping.Dispose()
    return $false
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434012/powerhsell-script-to-use-returned-value/75434332#75434332 Use Test-NetConnection -ErrorAction Stop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: @rinatgadeev - The querent wishes to change the timeout setting for the ping; under Windows Powershell 5.1, neither `Test-NetConnection` nor `Test-Connection` allow this (although `Test-Connection` does allow it under Powershell 7.3).

Comment: `try {} catch {} finally {}` in Powershell is only triggered if the error generated in the `try` block is a _terminating_ error. Not all reported errors are necessarily terminating errors; on those cmdlets that allow it, `-ErrorAction Stop` converts nonterminating errors to terminating errors, allowing them to be handled in `try {} catch {} finally {}` constructs. You need to somehow convert errors generated by `$ping.Send()` into terminating errors.

Comment: `catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException]` works for me on PS 5.1

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I have version 5.1 and have a Test-NetConnection, although I may not have understood it correctly

Comment: @JeffZeitlin While correct for _cmdlets_, this doesn't apply to .NET method calls. When a .NET method throws an exception, it is always treated as a script-terminating error, unless explicitly catched.

Comment: @rinatgadeev - The cmdlet exists; it does not allow the changing of the timeout from the default value under Windows PowerShell 5.1. `Test-Connection` does not, either, under Windows PowerShell 5.1, but it does allow it under PowerShell 7.3. Unfortunately, the querent is using Windows PowerShell 5.1, which is why he needs to use System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping

Answer (score 0):

Use the output streams ([MSKB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3))

```
Test-Ping -comp abcdefg54321  2>$null
```